# How do I jailbreak my iPhone 11 so that it’s not carrier locked?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I bought an iPhone 11 from Sprint and also bought their unlimited data plan. I have been making my monthly payments for my services and my phone.  The thing is Sprint is so full of red tape and ridiculous charges that I am sick of it. Basically they're just stealing money from me and using the red tape for charges that are just ridiculous.  Is there a way for me to just break away from Sprint using this phone on another carrier?

Comment: Isn’t a carrier unlock something that is handled in a database on the carrier side?

Comment: you didn't buy a phone from Sprint, you are merely leasing it.  It is impossible to 'buy' a phone from Sprint any longer.

Comment: Note for future: It's cheaper in the long run to buy your phone directly from Apple. It will also be carrier unlocked from day one.

Answer (score 5):

Unlocking a phone is not the same as jail breaking.  Unlocking has to do with how your phone communicates on the carrier's network (and won’t on others), whereas jail breaking removes the iOS restrictions Apple has placed to secure your device.  They are mutually exclusive: you can have an unlocked phone that isn’t jail broken and vice versa.

In the US you can unlock your phone from the carrier once you’ve satisfied your contractual obligations, for free.  For instance, with AT&T, I was able to unlock an iPhone so that it could be moved to Verizon.  All I did was via the AT&T website, request an unlock code and within minutes, I received it, put it in the phone and “released” its carrier restriction.

From what you describe, you may not have satisfied your contractual obligation meaning the carrier has no incentive to unlock the phone.